# How to use recyclerView with LiveData

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm instantiate my RecyclerView like this:

Global var:

```
private MainViewModel mainViewModel;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
```

RecyclerView:

```
observeAll();
recyclerView= findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter();
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The problem is, I need to pass a List that i'm getting from `LiveData` to the `adapter`

I can get my List Like this:

```
private void observeAll() {
    mainViewModel.getAll().observe(this, new Observer<Animals>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Animals animals) {
            Log.i("MainActivity", String.valueOf(animals.getTotalResults()));
        }
    });
}
```

But if I try to set the adapter inside `onChange` it is not working

Comment: pass list to adapter via a method then use it in adapter, call notifyDatasetchanged

Comment: Tried this, somehow it keep giving me ```No adapter attached; skipping layout```

Comment: could be a result of an issue in your adapter or problematic solution implementation itself, post the complete code with the adapter for better answers

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use livedata and recyclerview is actually using ListAdapter instead of a regular recyclerview adapter. As listAdapter uses DIFF UTILS it will automatically update your list without refreshing everything as *notifyDataSetChanged()*, also it will update your list with only the elements that differ from the previous list.

You can check how to do in Java [here](https://github.com/kaushiknsanji/PagingSampleCodelab/blob/todo-starter-code/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/codelabs/paging/ui/ReposAdapter.java)